# How can I show the unix time in the Windows clock?

Tags: windows, clock

How can I show the current [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in the Windows clock?

Whenever I need it, I currently look it up on [this site](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/), but it would be easier if I could directly see it alongside the actual time on the clock.

Answer (score 1):

To customize the Clock’s display format, right-click on the clock and select T-Clock Properties. In the configuration window that opens, click on the Time Format tab. In this tab, check boxes for the options you want on the clock. To further customize the text appearance, click on the Clock Text tab.
As a user-request, recently a new feature was added to the software that allows display of Unix Epoch in the tray clock. I haven’t seen any other app that does this on Windows. If you need to see Unix Time on Windows, just add POSIX as a format specifier in the Custom Format field under Time Format tab. Hit Apply to immediately see the number of seconds elapsed since Unix Epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00. For new lines add \n to the format text.

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://sumtips.com/software/display-seconds-unix-epoch-time-windows-taskbar-clock/), [T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock) can show the unix time. This can be achieved by including the `POSIX` format specifier in the "Advanced clock format" field:

[image]

This format specifier results in the following clock:

[image]